# How can I make an Automator service run a Terminal and display the output?

Tags: terminal, automator, services, rar

I'm using Automator to run a shell script (Rar selected files) as a 'Service', so that I can just right click a folder and select the service. It works fine, but i've added verbose and testing (to see the progress and test results) so I need to see the output of the Terminal window to make sure the archive is ok. Is there a way to see the output in real time? or to take it an extra step echo the results?

here's the script that works in automator but the output is silent.

```
on run {input, parameters}
set nbFiles to count input

if nbFiles = 0 then
    display dialog "No files selected!" buttons {"OK"} default button 1
    return
end if

tell application "Finder"

    set archiveDir to (container of (item 1 of input) as string)
    if nbFiles = 1 then
        set archiveName to (name of (item 1 of input) as string)
    else
        set archiveName to "archive"
    end if

    if exists file (archiveDir & archiveName & ".rar") then
        set i to 2
        repeat while exists file (archiveDir & archiveName & "-" & i & ".rar")
            set i to i + 1
        end repeat
        set archiveName to archiveName & "-" & i
    end if

    set archiveDir to quoted form of POSIX path of archiveDir
    set archiveName to quoted form of (archiveName & ".rar")

    set listFiles to " "
    repeat with i in input
        set listFiles to listFiles & quoted form of ("." & POSIX path of (name of i as string)) & " "
    end repeat

end tell

do shell script "cd " & archiveDir & "; rar a -ol[a] -mt8 -m5- -y -s -m4 -t " & archiveName & listFiles

return input
end run
```

THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

Change the following line of *code*:

```
do shell script "cd " & archiveDir & "; rar a -ol[a] -mt8 -m5- -y -s -m4 -t " & archiveName & listFiles
```

To:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd " & archiveDir & "; rar a -ol[a] -mt8 -m5- -y -s -m4 -t " & archiveName & listFiles   
end tell
```